# Try to put jqgrid into div with predefined sizes

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

I have problems with inserting jqgrid and it's pager:
For example i have div with predefined sizes like:

```
var totalHeight = dy * unitHeight * scale + 'px';
var totalWidth = dx * unitWidth * scale + 'px';
```

And when i try to put pager with jqgrid table, pager has height = 0

```
var newTable = $("<table></table>");
var newPager = $("<div></div>");
newPager.attr("id", "pager");
newTable.attr("id", name);
newElement.append(newTable);
newElement.append(newPager);
```

Code of jqgrid:

```
newTable.jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local',
            data: testData,
            colNames: ['No', 'Module', 'Group', 'App', 'LastDate', 'DelayedBy'],
            colModel: [{
                name: 'no',
                index: 'no',
                //width: elemWidth,
                sorttype: 'int'
            },{
                name: 'module',
                index: 'module',
                //width: elemWidth
            },{
                name: 'group',
                index: 'group',
                //width: elemWidth
            },{
                name: 'app',
                index: 'app',
                //width: elemWidth
            },{
                name: 'lastDate',
                index: 'lastDate',
                //width: elemWidth
                //sorttype: 'date'
            },
            {
                name: 'delayedBy',
                index: 'delayedBy',
                //width: elemWidth
                //sorttype: 'date'
            }],
            rowNum: cols,
            pager: "#pager",
            caption: name,
            shrinkToFit: false
        });
```

Also I've tried to set bdiv like:

```
$('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').height(totalHeight);
$('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').height(totalWidth);
```

But i don't know how to fit it all.

And by the way is it possible to change dynamically font-size, like: $(.ui-jqgrid).css('font-size', 5*scale);
Is it possible to set font-size in jqgrid options without css?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because i tried to initialize jqgrid before appending to the body.
But i still have problem with resizing of rows height. Now i'm trying to find some css styles that can change height of each row.

By the way the problem now with pager. It has BIG buttons on the mobile devices and i don't know how to make them small and adjust pager to mobile devices.

So my solution:

```
 var newTable = $("<table></table>");
        var newPager = $("<div id='pager'></div>");
        newTable.attr("id", name);
        newElement.append(newTable);
        newElement.append(newPager);
        this.grid.addUnit(dx, dy, px, py, scale, newElement, {border:0, transparent:true});

        newTable.jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local',
            data: testData,
            colNames: ['No', 'Module', 'Group', 'App', 'LastDate', 'DelayedBy'],
            shrinkToFit: false,
            autowidth: true,
            //height: '200px',
            hidegrid: false,
            colModel: [{
                name: 'no',
                index: 'no',
                width: noWidth,
                sorttype: 'int'
            }, {
                name: 'module',
                index: 'module',
                width: elemWidth
            }, {
                name: 'group',
                index: 'group',
                width: elemWidth
            }, {
                name: 'app',
                index: 'app',
                width: elemWidth
            }, {
                name: 'lastDate',
                index: 'lastDate',
                width: elemWidth
                //sorttype: 'date'
            }, {
                name: 'delayedBy',
                index: 'delayedBy',
                width: elemWidth
                //sorttype: 'date'
            }],
            rowNum: 5,
            pager: "#pager",
            caption: name,
            loadComplete: function() {
                var grid = newTable;
                var ids = grid.getDataIDs();
                for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                    grid.setRowData(ids[i], false,   {
                        height: 0*scale + i * 2
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        newTable.jqGrid('setGridWidth', newElement.width(), true);

        $('.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th').css('font-size', 14 * scale + 'px');
        $('.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td').css('font-size', 14 * scale + 'px');
        $('.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-view').css('font-size', 14 * scale + 'px');
        $('.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager').css('font-size', 14 * scale + 'px');
        $('.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-input').css('font-size', 14 * scale + 'px');
        $('.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-titlebar').css('font-size', 14 * scale + 'px');
        $('#pager_center').css('width', newElement.width() - 6); 
        $('.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hdiv').css('height', 42*scale + 'px');
        $('.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager').css('width', newElement.width() - 6);

        var gboxHeight = $("#gbox_" + name).height() - $('#gbox_' + name + ' .ui-jqgrid-bdiv').height();

        newTable.jqGrid('setGridHeight', newElement.height() - gboxHeight);
```